# Retrieving user timeline with maxID giving unexpected result using twitteR package

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to retrieving the whole timeline of an account, after reading the twitter API, I have written the following code:

```
healthLeadersTimeline <- twListToDF(userTimeline("HealthLeaders", n=200, includeRts=TRUE, retryOnRateLimit=180))
write.table(healthLeadersTimeline, "health.csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE)
maxID <- getMaxID(last(healthLeadersTimeline)$id)
healthLeadersTimeline <- twListToDF(userTimeline("HealthLeader", n=200, maxID=maxID, includeRts=TRUE, retryOnRateLimit=180))
write.table(healthLeadersTimeline, "health.csv", sep=",", append=TRUE, col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
```

and getMaxID is implemented as follows:

```
getMaxID <- function (tweetID) {
  lastID <- as.numeric(tweetID)
  maxID <- toString(lastID -1)
  return(maxID)
}
```

This twitter account apparently have more than 400 tweets. yet at the second call for timeline, I can only retrieve 35 tweets.
What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do anything wrong, except may not read the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/user_timeline) :). 3200 is the maximum number of posts you can officially get from a timeline.

Comment: Yes, I have just found out that I can never pass the 3200 limit using python, but my code here using R only set n=200 every time. In the second call of userTimeline, only 200 tweets have been retrieved previously.

Comment: It looks like `userTimeline` handles paging internally. So you don't need to specify `maxID` unless you want to exclude tweets after a certain time. You can set `n=3200`. At least that is what twitterR docs imply. Also, if you do choose to supply `maxID` it means "less than" not "less than or equal," so don't subtract one. However, all this does not explain why you only get 35 tweets and not 200. I would remove `maxID`, try different values of `n` and inspect the tweets you do get to see which ones are geting dropped.

Comment: In the documentation page you provided, it says that maxID is inclusive, I was doing the minus one according to the [instruction](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines). Thanks for you reply, yes, I would try to inspect on the actual tweets retrieved.